# Visudo - NOPASSWD does not work

Tags: sudo, alma-linux

I have added the users to the wheel group and have tried disabling password for some commands. Since that did not work, I tried disabling it for all commands:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)        NOPASSWD: ALL
```

However, I am still prompted for the password. I have setup the exact same settings on a different machine and the other machine works without issues. They are all AlmaLinux 8 machines but one does not work for some reason.

I've removed all the other users to test and it still does not work. Here's what I have configured and it does not work

```
Defaults rootpw
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)        NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a cloud environment and there was the following entry in `/etc/sudoers.d/waagent`:

```
clouduser ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

Removed the file and everything is working as intended.